# Wait until Meteor.subscribe is ready

Tags: meteor, ddp

I would like to know how to wait until `Meteor.subscribe` is ready. This means that I want to write a blocking code.

I am subscribing to a collection from a different server through DDP connection and want to wait until the subscription is finished before moving to the next line.

Currently I can pass `onReady` callback as the last argument of `Meteor.subscribe` but the code is asynchronous and won't wait until subscription is ready. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by "the code is asynchronous and won't wait until subscription is ready"? can't you just move your code into your onReady callback?

Comment: @ChristianFritz I wish I could but I have a good reason for this to be blocking. Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: i don't think there are fibers or futures on the client, so I don't see how you could block *anything*. I think browsers are intentionally designed that way to ensure that no bad javascript code will ever freeze the tab.. but I'm speculating.

Comment: The browser will detect that your script is not responding and terminate it if you have blocking calls.